# Integer equal to 3 not meeting ==3 condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript/jQuery code used to make image transitions. $(obj) is a box containing two images, which is the size of each image. The following snippet of code is used to choose a new location outside of $(obj)'s borders, which is different from the previous location used (since one image sliding to the right while a new one comes from the left looks a lot better than one sliding to the right while another comes from the right.)

```
            var newLoc = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
            if ($(obj).data('lastloc') == newLoc) {
                console.log("FIXED "+newLoc);
                if (newLoc == 3) newLoc = 2;
                if (newLoc == 2) newLoc = 3;
                if (newLoc == 0) newLoc = 1;
                if (newLoc == 1) newLoc = 0;
                console.log("WITH "+newLoc);
            }
```

The issue I'm having is that both Chrome and Firefox are outputting this in the JavaScript console:

```
FIXED 3
WITH 3
```

How is this possible?

Comment: if `if ($(obj).data('lastloc') == newLoc) {` passes, both `console.log` calls will be executed. One suggestion: always use curly braces, even when you don't have to. It'll save you many hours of frustrating debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to properly map the newLoc variable to a different number, you can use an object which would involve making this change.

Change

```
if (newLoc == 3) newLoc = 2;
if (newLoc == 2) newLoc = 3;
if (newLoc == 0) newLoc = 1;
if (newLoc == 1) newLoc = 0;
```

to

```
var newLoc = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
var loc = { 3: 2, 2: 3, 0: 1, 1: 0 };
if ($(obj).data('lastloc') == newLoc) {
 console.log("FIXED "+newLoc);
 newLoc = loc[newLoc] || newLoc;
 console.log("WITH "+newLoc);
}
```

Comment: I'm now glad I posted this silly question. This is definitely the best way of doing something like this, since it's very easy to change the behaviour later on, add new positions, etc.

Comment: In this particular case, you could just use a linear array `var loc = [1,0,3,2]` instead of an object.

Answer (score 10):

You need `else if`. It is just falling through here

```
if (newLoc == 3) newLoc = 2;
if (newLoc == 2) newLoc = 3;
```

Try this instead

```
if (newLoc == 3) newLoc = 2;
else if (newLoc == 2) newLoc = 3;
else if (newLoc == 0) newLoc = 1;
else if (newLoc == 1) newLoc = 0;
```

or use a proper `switch`

Comment: or a switch statement

Comment: Well, this has been an embarrassing revelation. No idea how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Using a debugger definitely helps in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

You would use `else` so that only one of the conditions are handled:

```
if (newLoc == 3) newLoc = 2;
else if (newLoc == 2) newLoc = 3;
else if (newLoc == 0) newLoc = 1;
else if (newLoc == 1) newLoc = 0;
```

You can also use a switch:

```
switch (newLoc) {
  case 3: newLoc = 2; break;
  case 2: newLoc = 3; break;
  case 0: newLoc = 1; break;
  case 1: newLoc = 0; break;
}
```

Or conditional operators:

```
newLoc =
  newLoc == 3 ? 2 :
  newLoc == 2 ? 3 :
  newLoc == 0 ? 1 :
  newLoc == 1 ? 0 :
  newLoc;
```

If those four values are the only values that the variable can have, you can even calculate the new value. Just flipping bit zero will give you the new value:

```
newLoc ^= 1;
```

Comment: I do rather like that binary trick :D It didn't occur to me that there would be a ^= operator in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Because your logic is messed up:

```
 if (newLoc == 3) newLoc = 2;
 if (newLoc == 2) newLoc = 3;
```

if it is 3 then it goes to 2 then it goes right back to 3.

you have to change them to `else if` statements after the first if